# question about windows forms checkbox

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void frmSearch_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'bookdatabaseDataSet.Dist_Year' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    this.dist_YearTableAdapter.Fill(this.bookdatabaseDataSet.Dist_Year);
    // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'bookdatabaseDataSet.Dist_Auth' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    this.dist_AuthTableAdapter.Fill(this.bookdatabaseDataSet.Dist_Auth);
    // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'bookdatabaseDataSet.Book' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    this.bookTableAdapter.Fill(this.bookdatabaseDataSet.Book);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form f4 = new Confirm();
    f4.Show();
    Hide();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to Exit?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }   
}
```

my question is:
I want from the form to give me error message if I didn't check any of the check boxes. what is the correct code for it? and where should I right it? and thanks a lot for your concern.
[form of windows application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Q4Jo.png)

Comment: The C# language doesn't have any checkboxes. Maybe you're talking about the Windows Forms CheckBox, or the ASP.NET CheckBox, or the WPF CheckBox, or the Silverlight CheckBox, or some other checkbox?

Comment: yes, I am talking about windows forms checkBox! thanks for ur concern! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to ensure at least one checkbox is checked when `button1` is clicked, right? If so, place it at the beginning of `button1_Click` event.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!checkbox1.Checked && !checkbox2.Checked && !checkbox100.Checked)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please select a checkbox.", this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        checkbox1.Focus();
    }
    else
    {
        Form f4 = new Confirm();
        f4.Show();
        Hide();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For every checkbox do a checkbox.Checked test (boolean AND) and display a message box.

If you wanted to prevent the closing of the application then you have to handle the closing event and set CANCEL to true in this case.

```
void HandleFormClosing (object sender, CancelEventArgs args)
{
   if (checkbox1.Checked && checkbox2.Checked)
      return;

   MessageBox.Show ("Need to check all boxes");
   args.Cancel = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will not give you a direct answer (work-done-just-for-you kind of answer), but should point you in the right direction:

[Finding the selected Radiobutton's value in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732540/finding-the-selected-radiobuttons-value-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [custom validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950965.aspx#winforms03162004_topic3).

But you could also get rid of the checkboxes and assume that if the user types in the textbox then they want to do a search on the field.

Start with search button disabled and only enable it when at least one field has text in it.