# Best way to find the value of the selected radio button in a group of radio buttons (associated with GroupName attribute) in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, radio-button

I am working on retrieving the value of the selected radio button out of three radio buttons that share the same GroupName attribute. I will need to find this value with the C# code-behind as I am using an MVP pattern in my application and will pass this value from the code-behind to the presenter.

In the .aspx file:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td style="width: 25px">
         <asp:Label ID="rmd" runat="server" Text="*" CssClass="RequiredField" />
      </td>
      <td align="left" style="width: 350px">
         <asp:Label ID="rmd2" runat="server" Text="Raw material dimensions (width, length, thickness)" CssClass="FieldHeader"></asp:Label>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom">
         <asp:RadioButton ID="rbRawMaterialDimensions" runat="server" TextAlign="Left" CssClass="FieldHeader"
                                GroupName="PlatesManufacturedInHouse" />
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td style="width: 25px">
         <asp:Label ID="hpn" runat="server" Text="*" CssClass="RequiredField" />
      </td>
      <td align="left" style="width: 350px">
         <asp:Label ID="hpn2" runat="server" Text="New HPN Created (main OR raw material item)" CssClass="FieldHeader"></asp:Label>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom">
         <asp:RadioButton ID="rbNewHPN" runat="server" TextAlign="Left" CssClass="FieldHeader"
                                GroupName="PlatesManufacturedInHouse" />
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td style="width: 25px">
         <asp:Label ID="na" runat="server" Text="*" CssClass="RequiredField" />
      </td>
      <td align="left" style="width: 350px">
         <asp:Label ID="na2" runat="server" Text="Not Applicable" CssClass="FieldHeader"></asp:Label>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom">
         <asp:RadioButton ID="rbNotApplicable" runat="server" TextAlign="Left" CssClass="FieldHeader"
                                GroupName="PlatesManufacturedInHouse" />
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
         <asp:Label ID="Label24" runat="server" Text="Required Field Missing: An item classification is required."
                                TextAlign="Left" CssClass="Warning" Visible="False" />
   </tr>
</table>
```

I have tried using the `<asp:RadioButtonList>` tag, but as I need to include labels for each button (as well as add validation in the future), it seems that using the `GroupName` attribute is the best solution currently, as far as what I have read online.

I have checked over other StackOverflow questions and answers to find the best way to find the selected radio button and it's associated value, but I can not seem to find the best possible solution in my scenario. The closest scenario to my question is [this question I found on here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732540/how-can-i-find-the-selected-radiobuttons-value-in-asp-net)

I am confused as to what the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5732634/9617466) to the question means when it says:

> where radioButtonsContainer is the container of the radiobuttons

I created an `<asp:Panel ID="PanelPlatesManufacturedInHouse" runat="server" CssClass="outercontainer">` tag surrounding the three radio buttons, but am not sure if this is the proper way to use a container.

I seem to be stuck in my implementation now, if anyone knows the best way to go forward  with this, I would appreciate the help :)!

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give your table a class or ID, and loop all the Radio Buttons in that table to find the value.

So add an ID

```
<table id="myTable">
```

Then find the correct value

```
<script>
    function findRadioValue() {
        $('#myTable input[type=radio]').each(function () {
            if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                alert($(this).val());
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Update

I somehow though it was jQuery, my bad. But I've created a method to get the correct control ID based on the GroupName. Note that this uses a Master Page. If you do not use one you use `foreach (var control in Page.Controls)`

```
public string getRadioButtonIdByGroupName(string groupName)
{
    //loop all controls on the page
    foreach (var control in (Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1") as ContentPlaceHolder).Controls)
    {
        //check if the control is a radiobutton
        if (control is RadioButton)
        {
            //cast the control to a radiobutton
            var radioButton = control as RadioButton;

            //check if it is the correct group name and if it's checked
            if (radioButton.GroupName == groupName && radioButton.Checked)
            {
                //return the value
                return radioButton.ID;
            }
        }
    }

    return "NotFound";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am using an MVP pattern on the back-end and will need to retrieve the information using the C# code-behind to pass to the presenter. I will edit my question to be more clear on this, but if I was using JS I would definitely try this out!

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for. I used this answer by including a Panel around my radio button section and parsing the panel for the radio buttons. This with your logic solved my problem. Thanks again!!